# How to resolve Rail 6 deploy error on AWS Elastic Beanstalk for ruby 2.7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web-deployment, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to deploy a Rails 6 app on AWS via Elastic Beanstalk.

When I run `eb deploy`, it fails. 
When I look at the logs, I see this message

```
2020/06/03 14:19:51.457403 [ERROR] rbenv: version `2.7.0' is not installed (set by /var/app/staging/.ruby-version)

2020/06/03 14:19:51.457439 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [stage ruby application]. Stop running the command. Error: install dependencies in Gemfile failed with error Command /bin/sh -c bundle config set --local deployment true failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:rbenv: version `2.7.0' is not installed (set by /var/app/staging/.ruby-version)
```

However, when I  `eb ssh` and run `ruby -v` I see that I am running `ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux]`

So I updated my `Gemfile` and `.ruby-version` to `ruby 2.7.1` to match my AWS environment.

When I `cd /var/app/staging` 
and `cat .ruby-version` 
I get `2.7.1`

So why is this deploy failing? I am not requiring `ruby 2.7.0` anywhere in my project.

I've made sure to `git push`, so I know my Gemfile is pushed my to repo.
I am going crazy trying to get this Rails App deployed.

Comment: Try changing the Deployment Policy to Immutable (under the "Rolling updates and deployments" config). This will deploy your code on a fresh server each time, ruling out the possibility of old files getting read.

Comment: @David I am currently facing the same problem, how did you manage to resolve this please?

Comment: @littleforest Your solution doesn't see to fix the problem

Comment: @chrisgeeq - I have spent over 160 hours on this and I still have not figured it out. I haven't given up, but I am just taking a break from this.

Comment: @DavidLee had the same issue, though my problem was resolved by rebuilding the environment, have you tried? Also make sure your gemfile and ruby-version are referencing the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is to create a zip file in the root directory of your app:

```
zip ../rails-default.zip -r * .[^.]
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ruby-rails-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set up ruby and make it as default based on your requirement.
Just set up some config file in .ebextensions and set instructions to install ruby version you require and make it default.
e.g.

1. Create file in .ebextensions `00_ruby_install.config`
2. Add content which will install ruby

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/09_ruby_install.sh" :
    mode: "000775"
    owner: root
    group: users
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      ... Add ruby install instructions here ...
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a .ruby-version file in the root of your directory that states a different ruby version, like in your case it would be ruby-2.7.0, just change it to ruby-2.7.1 or whatever is in your Gemfile.